# Excel: Get column Value based on anther column Value

Tags: excel

I have a row which contains a number: example A1 = 10
Now I want to get the value of Row B10, but the Row here is B(Value of A1). 
i need some thing like  =B(A1))
so this value will = value of Column B but the row is based on value of A1

Comment: Use `Indirect` function: `=INDIRECT("B"&A1)`

Comment: Better than INDIRECT is iNDEX: =INDEX(B:B,A1)

Comment: +1 for XOR, Index() is better as it'll not be volatile.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you can use [INDIRECT](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html)

`=INDIRECT("B"&A1)`

Answer (score 0):

use indirect:

```
=INDIRECT("B" & A1)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @philip: sorry, i don't want to post in the wrong place - but what am i missing, how is this not an answer to the question?

Comment: Don't worry - it's the automatic flag text, I wanted to comment that it would be better to elaborate on your answer, provinding explanation of why INDIRECT would solve the problem and what the OP was missing or getting wrong, but as it stands your answer is still correct.