# A cell contains the number of row and I want to get the value of that row on specific column

Tags: excel

First, sorry that I can't provide you with table.. I have no idea how to use this .

I have A column containing the number of rows. For example, A1 is 900. Then I want to put the value of B900 on column C

Is there any function for this one?

what I have tried is add "B" to A1 to make B900 and use =value(A1), but it gives me #value!

Can you please help me

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of [Excel: Get column Value based on anther column Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526982/excel-get-column-value-based-on-anther-column-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'INDIRECT' built-in function of Excel:

Example:

Suppose you have A column containing the number of rows. For example, A1 is 900. Then you want to put the value of B900 on column C

in Cell C2 you can type the formula as

```
=INDIRECT("B"&A1)
```

And you will definitely get value of B900 in the cell C2

Comment: Please Accept make my answer as a Correct Answer if it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",A1))

hope it works